# Screenshots location while running the puppeteer script

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have created a Puppeteer script to run in `offline`, I have got the below code to take the screenshot. While running the `offline-login-check.js` script from the command prompt, could some one please advise where the screen shots are added ?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    chromeWebSecurity: false, 
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  try {
    // Create a new page
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    // Connect to Chrome DevTools
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
    // Navigate and take a screenshot
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await page.goto('https://sometestsite.net/home',{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
    //await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.evaluate('navigator.serviceWorker.ready');
    console.log('Going offline');
    await page.setOfflineMode(true);
 // Does === true for the main page but the fallback content isn't being served.
    page.on('response', r => console.log(r.fromServiceWorker()));
    await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png',fullPage: true})
    await page.waitForSelector('mat-card[id="route-tile-card]');
    await page.click('mat-card[id="route-tile-card]');
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    } catch(e) {
      // handle initialization error
    console.log ("Timeout or other error: ", e)
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: [pptr.dev - screenshot](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions)
`If path is a relative path, then it is resolved relative to current working directory`

Comment: This is my test file path `C:\work\sun\UiTests`. I haven't see the screenshot.png file  in that root location

Comment: tried with this [snippet](https://pastebin.com/Te5D0eeu) but it works fine :(

Comment: Added my full code, I am trying to run the `node offline-login-check.js` from command prompt.

Comment: Actually trying to see if `offline-login-check.js` work with my site, but nothing is working for me,neither offline nor the screenshot capture.

Comment: run this [snippet](https://pastebin.com/0iX4haMX) <-- it's basically your code w/o `waitFor` methods and then in the same directory `ls | GREP .png ` and it shows `screenshot2.png` properly. The problem might be specified to your page :(

Comment: `await page.evaluate('navigator.serviceWorker.ready');` i think there's a problem

Comment: Awesome, this is working fine, please post your answer, I will accept  it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  try {
    // Create a new page
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Connect to Chrome DevTools
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    // Navigate and take a screenshot
    await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    // await page.evaluate('navigator.serviceWorker.ready');
    console.log('Going offline');
    await page.setOfflineMode(true);
 // Does === true for the main page but the fallback content isn't being served.
    page.on('response', r => console.log(r.fromServiceWorker()));
    await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot2.png',fullPage: true})
    // await page.waitForSelector('mat-card[id="route-tile-card]');
    // await page.click('mat-card[id="route-tile-card]');
    } catch(e) {
      // handle initialization error
    console.log ("Timeout or other error: ", e)
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

then in command line run `ls | GREP .png` and you should see screenshot there. Be aware i take rid of `await page.evaluate('navigator.serviceWorker.ready');` which might be specified to your website

Answer (score 1):

Your script is perfect. There is no problem with it!

The screenshot.png should be on the directory that you run the `node offline-login-check.js` command.

If its not there, maybe you are getting some error/timeout before the `page.screenshot` command runs. Since your script is ok, this can be caused by network issues or issues with the page. For example, if your page has a never ending connection (like WebSocket), change the "networkidle0" to "networkidle2" or "load", otherwise the first `page.goto` will get stuck.

Again, your script is perfect. You don't have to change it.